# Have an irremovable question mark at the end of html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked around for ages trying to figure out this, hope you can help me.

Basically I have a feature on my site where the user can post a question. Essentially I want a  permanent question mark at the end of what they're typing. The question mark is already added in the back end so this is strictly a visual problem.

The question mark moves up when they type.

I can't attach a photo but you can imaging :

The user typing here and after the type line there's a trailing question mark (type line-->)|?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why don't you do css?

Comment: I have no idea of what your question is. Can you describe it a little bit better?

Comment: You really can't do this. It'll just interfere with the user's attempts to type their question.

Comment: @DanielA.White How do you do that ?

Comment: You should consider appending question mark on change(if something is left after trimming spaces, of course) and not on the key up.

Comment: This seems unnecessary and frustrating to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this :

```
$('#a').keyup(function(){
  var v = this.value.replace(/\?/g, '') + '?';
  if (this.value != v) this.value = v;
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/emupoy/3/edit)

But users don't really like when the content of the input changes of its own. I'd avoid this if possible.

This second version puts a space before the ? :

```
$('#a').keyup(function(){
  var v = this.value.replace(/ ?\?/g, '') + ' ?';
  if (this.value != v) this.value = v;
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/emupoy/4/edit)

Comment: I edited the first replace to more accurately do what the OP asks for. This will just clean up whatever trailing question marks exist in the string, and not *all the question marks that were there, so the user can add a question mark into their larger statement that isn't at the end.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I think you didn't test your change.

Comment: You're correct... sorry... remove the g at the end :) But why are you stripping out ALL the question marks?

Comment: I didn't find a really working way to have a ? in the middle of the question, that's why I remove them all.

Comment: you can arrow over to add a ? (not elegant, but even MORE frustrating if after you do that it disappears!)

Comment: @dystroy, I just copied and pasted your solution, but I realize you've changed your code since then.  I was going to point out the many annoyances of this solution but I can see you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Use a little javascript.

Attach an event onto the onkeyup event of the tickbox, and whenever it fires, check to see if the contents end with a question mark. If it doesn't, then add it!

Personally though, it would annoy me, as a user-I'd prefer to only see the question mark once I'be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps instead recommend that you do a check on the server to see if the question contains a question mark (or multiple) at the end, then replace/add the single question mark.

As stated already, it's not really friendly to force a certain input - do the proper checks yourself and take the burden off the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply visual reinforcement, then it might be easiest to put a text or graphical question mark *outside* the text input, possibly in an interesting color, like bold green.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to be trying to manipulate the `input` as the user is typing; you will likely always run into edge cases where the content gets mangled. If it's purely for presentational purposes, just add a `?` character just after the input; if you surround it with something like a `span`, you can target it with CSS to adjust its size or font weight to make it more obvious:

```
.jumbo
{
    font-size: 2em;
}

<input /><span class="jumbo">?</span>
```

An alternate solution (but overkill if you aren't already using it) is to use an icon font like FontAwesome and add, say, the question-mark icon: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/question/

```
<input /><i class="icon-question icon-large"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the editable text inside a contenteditable span followed by another span that has the non editable question mark.

http://jsfiddle.net/Paawn/1/

```
<div class="box">
    <span contenteditable="true">This is content i can edit</span>
    <span class="question-mark">?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for something that shouldn't really be done... but if it is going to be done, this is a very cool and decent way to go about it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty decent solution built off of ideas above and elsewhere on stack overflow.  Using jQuery

Just add the following snippet and then add the class `questionableInput` to your `input`
`<input id="yourInput" type="text" name="theInput" class="questionableInput"/>`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var input = this.get(0);
        if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
        if ('selectionStart' in input) {
            // Standard-compliant browsers
            return input.selectionStart;
        } 
    }

    $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
        var input = this.get(0);
        if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
        if ('selectionStart' in input) {
            // Standard-compliant browsers
            input.selectionStart = pos;
            input.selectionEnd = pos;
        } 
    }

    $(".questionableInput").keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 13
          || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 16 || e.keyCode == 36 || e.keyCode == 63
         || e.keyCode == 35 || e.ctrlKey) {
          return;
      }
      var positionBeforeMessingWithIt = $(this).getCursorPosition();
      if (this.value.slice(-1)!='?') this.value += '?';
      if (this.value.slice(-2)=="??") this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
      $(this).setCursorPosition(positionBeforeMessingWithIt);
   });

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YpEgN/2/

Comment: Alot of code but this seems to be the type of script I was looking for, thanks. Thank you everyone for your input!!!